# Merchant's affiliate marketing policy template

Tags: affiliate, privacy-policy

A client of mine is a merchant, and we're going to test the waters with an in-house affiliating program.

We need to create a policy document that affiliate marketers must agree to before they're accepted as publishers.

Do you know where I could find a policy template for affiliate programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an elance provider who was able to provide a policy document for about AUD$120.